# Обновление данных в БД SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

В приложении получаем данные с сервера, после чего эти данные заносятся в базу данных SQLite(хранятся локально, чтобы приложение могло работать и без Интернета). Предположим, данные изменились, поэтому их нужно поменять и в базе данных. Как проверить совпадают ли новые данные загруженные с сервера и данные в БД SQLite, и если нет, то как их обновить в таблице?

Comment: Чтобы сравнить, надо получить к себе. Если уже получил к себе - зачем сравнивать, когда проще прибить старое и сохранить новое? А для проверки - надо, чтобы сервер умел вернуть приложению версию либо дату актуальности данных, и при несоответствии приложение инициирует процесс обновления.

Comment: Возможно немного не по теме отвечу. Если вместо чистого SQLite использовать Room. То он возьмет на себя всю эту работу. То есть там можно указать не большие настройки. Он вам и добавит новые записи, если нету, отредактирует те, которые нужны.  И самое интересное что это он сделает в одном запросе к базе данных.